# Heuristics of Heine-Borel property

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, intuition

A metric space $X$ is said to have the [Heine-Borel property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem#Heine-Borel_property) if every closed and bounded set is compact. There are two well-known facts about this property:

- Every Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ adopts the Heine-Borel property.
- No infinite dimensional Banach space adopts the Heine-Borel property.

What is the intuition behind the difference between these two types of metric spaces? So far I've mostly dealt with Euclidean spaces, thus have a tendency to associate compactness being the same as closed and bounded. What are the heuristics behind this property failing for infinite dimensional cases?

Comment: When I compare topologies in finite vs infinite dimensions, "failure of the Heine--Borel property" is *itself* the heuristic feature. This is a very basic property that should underscore your intuition of norm topologies in functional analysis. I know this isn't a helpful answer though. If you want to really get down to fundamentals, the necessary keys are: (1) the completeness of a Banach space implies that its (algebraic) basis must be uncountable, and (2) Baire category theorem. Uncountability seems to be what's going on behind the scenes here.

Comment: (But at this point I'm just describing the proof of your second bullet point, which might not be the "heuristic" you're looking for.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A set in a metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded. Here totally bounded means that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exist finitely many open balls of radius $\varepsilon$ that cover the set. In $\mathbb R^n$, every bounded set is totally bounded (this would be a good exercise to prove).

In infinite dimensional Banach spaces, this is no longer the case. Take $S = \{e_n : n=1,2,\ldots\}\subset \ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$, where $e_n$ is the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ standard orthonormal basis vector (when viewed in $\ell^2$). Then clearly $S$ is bounded as $\|x\|_\infty = 1$ for all $x\in S$, but for all $x,y\in S$ we have $d(x,y)=1$, so for $\varepsilon=1$ there can be no finite collection of $\varepsilon$ balls that cover the set. Hence $S$ is not totally bounded.

Comment: +1 Highly intuitive answer. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.